# Passing an array of objects into database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, forms

I have 2 page form which allows user to add processes and then assign stuff to each process. So the problem now is how to save array of processes to database,(inserting each process in separate row). In my database I have two tables: `project` and `process`.

So array of processes should be store in the `process` table You can view and test form here: http://headcount.esy.es/drag/ What I need at least some ideas on how can I pass and split this values into database.

So here is SQL code which should insert data to database but its not working:

```
require_once 'helper/helper.clean_data.php';
require_once('inc/config.php');
require 'model/model.project.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit']) || isset($_POST['save']))
{   
    global $array_object;
    //getting values for the first table 'project'
    if (isset($_POST["holdcode"])) {$holdcode = $_POST["holdcode"];}
    if (isset($_POST["holdtitle"])) {$holdtitle = $_POST["holdtitle"];}
    if (isset($_POST["leader"])) {$leader = $_POST["leader"];}
    //getting values for the second table 'process'
    if (isset($_POST["holdprocess"])) {$holdprocess = $_POST["holdprocess"];}
    if (isset($_POST["holdnumber"])) {$holdnumber = $_POST["holdnumber"];}
    if (isset($_POST["procleader"])) {$procleader = $_POST["procleader"];}

    $counta = 1;
}
else
{
    $counta = 0;
}

function insertRecord()
{
    global $holdcode, $holdtitle, $leader, $holdprocess, $holdnumber, $procleader;
    //* database connection   
    $host="mysql.hostinger.my"; // Host name
    $username="u624343149_pp"; // Mysql username
    $password="123987"; // Mysql password
    $db_name="u624343149_pp"; // Database name

    // Connect to server and select database.
    $con = mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password", "$db_name");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
    $holdcode = cleanInputData($holdcode);
    $holdtitle = cleanInputData($holdtitle);
    $leader = cleanInputData($leader);

    $holdprocess = cleanInputData($holdprocess);
    $holdnumber = cleanInputData($holdnumber);
    $procleader = cleanInputData($procleader);

    $holdcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $holdcode);
    $holdtitle = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $holdtitle);
    $leader = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $leader); 

    $holdprocess = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $holdprocess);
    $holdnumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $holdnumber); 
    $procleader = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $procleader);

    $result = getLastReportNo();

    if (!$result) {
        die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //** creating project number using current date 
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 0)
    {
        $year = date("y");
        $month = date("m");
        $number = sprintf("%04d", 1);
        $yearStr = strval($year);
        $monthStr = strval($month);
        $numberStr = strval($number);
        $projectNo = $yearStr . $monthStr . $numberStr;
    }
    else
    {   
        if ($row_last = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $row_last[0] = cleanOutputData($row_last[0]);
            $projectNo = $row_last[0];
            $extractedNumberStr = substr($projectNo, -4);
            $extractedYearMonthStr = substr($projectNo, 0, 4);

            $year = date("y");
            $month = date("m");
            $yearStr = strval($year);
            $monthStr = strval($month);
            $currentYearMonthStr = $yearStr . $monthStr;

            if($extractedYearMonthStr == $currentYearMonthStr)
            {
                $extractedNumber = intval($extractedNumberStr);
                $extractedNumber++;
                $extractedNumber = sprintf("%04d", $extractedNumber);
                $extractedNumberStr = strval($extractedNumber);
                $projectNo = $currentYearMonthStr . $extractedNumberStr;
            }
            else
            {
                $number = sprintf("%04d", 1);
                $projectNo = $currentYearMonthStr . $number;
            }
        }
    }

    mysqli_set_charset($con, 'utf8');

    //query result inserting values into the first table 'project'
    $result = insertNewProject($projectNo,$_SESSION['login_user'],$holdcode,$holdtitle, $leader);       
    // Check result
    if (!$result) 
    {
        die('Invalid queryyyyyyyyy: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    $result = getLastReportNo();

    if (!$result) 
    {
        die('Invalidddddd query: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    //splitting an array and inserting an array in a second table 'process'
    if ($row_last = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $row_last[0] = cleanOutputData($row_last[0]);
        $projectNo = $row_last[0];

        foreach($holdprocess as $process)
        {
            if(!empty($holdnumber))
            {
                if (is_array($holdnumber) || is_object($holdnumber))
                {
                    foreach($holdnumber as $number)
                    {
                        if($process == $number)
                        {
                            $record = insertProcess($projectNo,$process,$procleader, $number);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (!$record) {
                        die('Invaliiiiiid query: ' . mysql_error());
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }

}

function verifyFormFields()
{
    global $holdcode, $holdtitle, $leader, $holdprocess, $holdnumber, $procleader;

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kuching');
    $date1 = date("Y-m-d");
    $date1=date_create($date1);

    if(empty($holdcode)){
        return "<p id ='err'>Please Enter Project Code</p>";
    }
    else if(empty($holdtitle)){
        return "<p id ='err'>Please Enter Project Name</p>";    
    }

    if(isset($_POST['save']))
    {
        //Get the existing report no from cookie
        $projectNo = $_COOKIE["projectNo"];
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Where are the two methods being called, insertRecord() and verifyFormFields()?  You're showing where they're defined, but where are they being called?

Comment: @Craig inside my second form, create2.php. The thing is i am successfully able to insert data for the first table 'project', problem is only with an array.

Answer (score 1):

You could json_encode the array before insert and json_decode it when you retrieve it.